# password authentication failed for user "saleor"

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, saleor

password authentication failed for user "saleor"
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "saleor"

when migrating the first time
 if it's something related  to database  please someone help me to figure this out
I'm using Postgres  as the saleor documentation  says but I can't pass this migrations point 
I read somewhere I have to create a database called saleor with saleor as a user with password 'saleor' who is a superuser and if that is the solution tell me how to do that

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 3):

```
DATABASES = {
  "default": dj_database_url.config(default="postgres://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/saleor", conn_max_age=600)
}
```

Postgres is my username, and 12345 is my password for username i.e postgres and saleor is database name. you can change database name to any. If you did not change username,password, and database name the it takes default one.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Remove everything inside migration folder for app, except the **init**.py file.

Step 2: Delete or Truncate Your Current Database which is 'saleor'

Step 3: Create the initial migrations and generate the database schema using folowing commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Step 4: Now you can Create new Super user using following command

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```